# Looking for a nicer python syntax to pass multiple parameters to a single-parameterized lambda

Tags: python, syntax, lambda

Let's take this code as an example (sort dict items by value):

```
sorted(d.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1])
```

The definition of key as a single-argument functor dictates this ugly lambda.

Now, in [this book](http://joelgrus.com/2015/04/26/data-science-from-scratch-first-principles-with-python/) I've seen some examples that use a much nicer syntax, like that:

```
sorted(d.items(), key=lambda (k,v): v)
```

But, unfortunately, this gives me a syntax error (under python 3.4).

Does such syntax exist? In which version(s)?

Comment: it works fine in Python 2.7.6;  I'd like to know as well as you do why it doesn't in Python 3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was unfortunately [removed in Python3](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/).

:-(

The idea was that this hinders introspection. Instead of figuring out how a function is called by the signature, it would require analyzing bytecode (*not* the syntax tree).

Answer (score 3):

Replacing the lambda altogether is the use-case for `operator.itemgetter`:

```
sorted(d.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

Comment: You're right, but I always felt it went against the [zen](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) thingy: "there should be one, and preferably only one..." (quoting from memory). Lambdas are a strict superset of `itemgetter``. For a specific case, there's also ``itemgetter`` (which is probably faster, though).

Comment: Well, and `operator.itemgetter` is the one obvious way to do it right ;)

Comment: Keep in mind that `lambda` was nearly removed from Python 3, because it was felt there were better solutions (`itemgetter`, `attrgetter`, and `methodcaller` from the `operator` module; `functools.partial`, etc) for most of its use cases.

Answer (score 2):

The feature was removed in Python3 [PEP3113](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/).

As far as I know there is no workaround for the `lambda` case. You could do the following:

```
def f_unpack(f):
   def unpacking(args):
       return f(*args)
   return unpacking
```

and then use `f_unpack(lambda k, v: v)`. (And you'll have to find a more descriptive short name for `f_unpack`.